# admin-ajax.php (aborted) error when using jQuery.get

Tags: ajax, javascript

One thing that really confuse me is the following:

When I load a javascript file via Ajax and I watch the http requests thats being made, then I see the following error in Firebug: admin-ajax.php (aborted)

Please see this picture:

[image]

It is this jquery get file function that's causing this error:

```
jQuery.get('/assets/js/shop.js', function(data) { eval(data); });
```

If I remove the above script, then there is no error anymore.

Any suggestions?

EDIT1:

I already see why it's giving these aborted errors.
In the shop.js file there are some calls to the admin-ajax.php:

```
/* <![CDATA[ */
var wc_cart_fragments_params = {"ajax_url":"\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php","fragment_name":"wc_fragments"};
/* ]]> */
```

Should I place these CDATA in the body of my html or do I need to do something else?

Answer (score 1):

Are there any Console js errors? The admin-ajax.php is Wordpress's built in way of dealing with ajax so you should probably do something like this, assuming .get() would also work:

```
$.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
    alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
});
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: No there are no console errors. Please see the edit in my question.